# Reading xlsx into R and creating new header

Tags: header

I'm a newbie to R.

I read in an Excel file for a survey, but I started reading observations from the 3rd row of the excel file, as the survey download creates a first two rows of the question string (first row for all questions) followed by a second row of multiple choice questions (each option gets its own column except the first option, which is listed in the same column in the second row as the question in the first row).
So now, my dataframe starts with Row 3.

But now I need to create custom variable names - ie. new variable names for each column before I manipulate further. I'm looking for tips on how to best accomplish this.
What I am thinking:

1. Create an Excel file with the variable names, and then use this is as the header. I'm not quite sure which code I would use to do this.
2. Code the names as an empty dataframe, and then somehow merge this so the empty dataframe column names are the column names for the file I imported.

I would appreciate some suggestions on how best to do this!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please consider checking out [what topics can you ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), SO is for solving specific problems with programming, you should provide a code you have tried so far, describe problems, showing effort in trying to solve it yourself at first (what have you read before etc.), "I need to do this, give me the code" questions are mostly closed.